# Start service after all install actions are complete

Tags: service, wix, installation

I have a complex WIX installer that does various tasks / MSIs.  One of the MSIs installs a service after which a Database MSI runs and updates the app.config for that service to contains the correct connection strings.

Currently the service is started after it is installed (this is before the Database MSI runs) meaning it has incorrect connection strings.  How can I make the service start as the very last item in the installer so that it has the correct connection strings.

I assume this could be in the Bundle of the Bootstrapper but I cannot get that to work.  Here is the current code within the Product.wxs which starts the service.

```
<ServiceControl Id="StartEMService" Start="install" Name="EMService"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles only operate on packages so things like controlling services aren't supported. Your database package should have a `ServiceControl` element to stop (just in case) and restart the service. Schedule the action that updates the config file to be before the `StartServices` standard action.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, not quite as clean as I'd like but works and didnt take long to do